# Manage orientation change in my project

Tags: android, bluetooth, screen-orientation, onconfigurationchanged

I am working on application with bluetooth connectivity.
I have placed my bluetooth enabler (intent) code in onCreate() of my activity. 
 When orientation of the phone changes my phone is trying to reconnect the device. I have tried to handle Configurationchanges events from manifest and activity both, But it seems like not working for me.
 Please suggest me any solution for this I am running out of time.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Managed through configchanges from android manifest.
Thank you all of u...

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

  if (savedInstanceState != null)
  {
   menuOut[0] = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("slide");
  }else
  {
  initLayout();
  adapter = new MyAdapter(this);
  ((ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1)).setAdapter(adapter);
  }
 }
```

> this function are use outside oncreate method.

```
@Override
 protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  outState.putBoolean("slide", true);
  super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

 }
```

Comment: I was thinking to use onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() method instead..?

Comment: Hey I have manage this by configchanges=orientation to the activity from android manifest.
But still I have the problem with one activity. This consist of bluetooth enable dialog intent, loads at onCreate(). I have checked by logcat onCreate() is not calling when orientation changes but still bluetooth enable dialog reappears the time I change the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a boolean value to check if you have already connected to your bluetooth device. Use SharedPreferences to store this value and then check its value in the overridden "onResume()" function.

Comment: Hey Rameez thank you for your reply...
When orientation changes which method is called?
onCreate() or onResume()

Comment: Good question. Actually, both are called. So forget about the the onResume() function. It's redundant. Just use the boolean value and SharedPreferences. It should work. :)